# Use `.local` domain through router

Tags: ubuntu, domain, router, local

I have got application on my laptop (with Ubuntu) under nginx. And I have got a wifi router.

I want everybody connected to wifi can visit my application not through ip address, like

```
http://192.168.1.3
```

But through something like

```
http://site.local
```

What general settings should I use to make all this work (change `/etc/hosts`, make some settings on router etc)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your own name server, configure the 'local' domain on it, and configure your router to tell its clients to use that name server.

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu comes with mDNS?